# P4 How to Checkout file to a Specify ChangeList ? (Use Command Line)

Tags: command-line, perforce

I knew checkout file command line is

```
p4 edit "filepath" or p4 add "filepath"
```

And Create a new ChangeList command line is

```
p4 --field "Description=My pending change" --field "Files=" change -o | p4 change -i
```

But I want my checkouted files go to the changelist.

I tried this but it's not working

```
p4 edit "fileName" -c "ChangeListID"
```

I got this output : -c file not on client.

Answer (score 2):

Options go before the filename(s):

```
p4 edit -c changelist fileName
```